# Error with Leaflet Map - Unable to display tiles on the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping, gis

I am encountering an issue when drawing polygons, point, and line features on a map using the Leaflet.js library.

The polygon is correctly displayed on the map, but the moment I try to draw a point ** or **line, they **disappear **immediately after releasing the mouse click. I need assistance to correct this issue and make the drawing of points and lines on the map functional.

```
var map = L.map("leaflet-map", {
  center: [37.7749, -122.4194],
  zoom: 8,
});

let osm = L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}", {
  foo: "bar",
  attribution: "© OpenStreetMap contributors",
});
osm.addTo(map);

var CyclOSM = L.tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.tile-cyclosm.openstreetmap.fr/cyclosm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    attribution: "CyclOSM | Map data: © OpenStreetMap contributors",
  }
);

CyclOSM.addTo(map);

var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer(
  "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
  {
    attribution:
      "Tiles © Esri — Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community",
  }
).addTo(map);

let baseLayers = {
  "Esri World Imagery": Esri_WorldImagery,
  "Open Street Map": osm,
  "Cycl OSM": CyclOSM,
};
//Creates three feature groups for points, polygons, and lines on the map
var pointLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var polygonsLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var lineLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var polygon;
var point;
var line;
var allLayers = L.featureGroup([pointLayer, polygonsLayer, lineLayer]).addTo(
  map
);

//Add new shapes drawn on the map to the appropriate feature group
map.on("draw:created", function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;
  if (type === "point") {
    point = layer;
    point.addTo(pointLayer);
    point.addTo(map);
  } else if (type === "polygon") {
    polygon = layer;
    polygon.addTo(polygonsLayer);
    polygonsLayer.addTo(map);
  } else if (type === "line") {
    line = layer;
    line.addTo(lineLayer);
    lineLayer.addTo(map);
  }
});

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  draw: {
    marker: true,
    polyline: true,
    polygon: true,
    rectangle: true,
    circle: true,
  },
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define 5 types of shapes:
`marker, polyline, polygon, rectangle, and circle`

but in the feature group, you only catch `polyline`

To catch makers, you need to change this block:

```js
if (type === "point") {
    point = layer;
    point.addTo(pointLayer);
    point.addTo(map);
```

to:

```js
if (type === "marker") {
    point = layer;
    point.addTo(pointLayer);
    pointLayer.addTo(map);  //add the layer to the map
```

same for `polyline`, `rectangle` and `circle`.

You can have a look at the Leaflet Draw [documentation](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event), you can catch all shapes by not checking for type and directly adding the `e.layer` from the draw event to the map.